# Object data null sms still sent twilio authy

Tags: firebase, react-native, twilio, twilio-api, authy

Im trying to implement the authy-node phone verification with firebase functions and my app in react-native the message is sent to the correct mobile phone but for some reason the data I get back from the api is null any ideas out there

My Api firebase functions

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const authy = require('authy')('mySecret');


export const getCode = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const {
     number, countryCode
  } = data;

 return authy.phones().verification_start(number, countryCode, { via: 
'sms', locale: 'en', code_length: '4' }, (err: any, res: any) => {
    if (err) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(err);
    }
    return res;
});
});
```

and this is my call from my app

```
export default class test extends Component {

constructor() {
 super();
}

 componentWillMount() {
 const getCode = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getCode');
 getCode({number: 'theCorrectNumber', countryCode: '44'})
   .then(function (result) {
     const data = result;
     console.log(data)
   }).catch( function (error){
   console.log(error)
 })
}

render() {
 return (
  <View/>
 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From what I can see in the [Authy Node](https://github.com/evilpacket/node-authy) library that I'm assuming you're using, making a request to the API does not return a Promise. Instead it is built with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and responds to asynchronous requests using callbacks only. You do deal with the callback, but you are returning the result of calling the asynchronous function, which is `null`, rather than the result from the callback.

Perhaps including a callback as part of the function call would work better:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const authy = require('authy')('mySecret');

export const getCode = functions.https.onCall((data, callback) => {
  const { number, countryCode } = data;

  return authy
    .phones()
    .verification_start(
      number,
      countryCode,
      { via: 'sms', locale: 'en', code_length: '4' },
      callback
    );
});
```

You can then use it like this:

```
export default class test extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const getCode = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getCode');
    getCode({ number: 'theCorrectNumber', countryCode: '44' }, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(err);
      }
      const data = res;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <View />;
  }
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Yes I am using the authy node sorry for not motioning. As for what you provided I still get an sms on my device but now the console does not log anything not even an error or the 'res' any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firebase and using `functions.https.onCall` to define functions I'm afraid, so some of this was a bit of a guess. As you can see, I updated the function we defined to take a callback function and return to it, perhaps that's not possible with Firebase? I can see some documentation that suggests using promises to keep functions alive while they a processing asynchronously. Do you know any more about that?

Comment: yes I just added to your code the async and await and even putting a variable to equal all the function results in getting an Object with null again

Comment: `async componentWillMount () {
    const getCode = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getCode');
    const s = await getCode({ number: 'myNumber', countryCode: '44' }, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(err);
      }
      const data = res;
      console.log(res);
    });
    console.log(s)
  }`

Comment: without await s comes back with a promise

Comment: Ah, but nothing within `getCode` returns a promise, which is why it is `null`.

Comment: If Firebase is going to require promises, you might need to rewrite [the verification call](https://github.com/evilpacket/node-authy/blob/master/index.js#L110-L131) using something like [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).

Comment: ok, i'll look into it, I honestly do not no much about the subject. Thanks for your help